# IIS 7.5 issue on reading large CSV files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file, csv, iis, iis-7.5

I have an MVC 4 application that currently reads data from a CSV file (this is based on client requirements, even if I wanted to have a database for it). All is working well when I debug and run it from visual studio. However, when I deploy it on IIS 7.5, it is unable to read large CSV files (currently, the largest i have is around 6000kb). I tried different techniques on reading the files, but it just produces the same result. But small files are being read perfectly.

Here is my code in parsing the file:

```
 using (CsvReader csv =
          new CsvReader(new StreamReader(_filePath), false, ';'))
            {
                while (csv.ReadNextRecord())
                {
                    int fieldCount = csv.FieldCount;
                    string currentRow = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        currentRow += csv[i] + ";";                           

                    }
                    this.AddKYCFolder(this.CreateKYCFolder(currentRow.Split(';')));
                }
            }
```

Any ideas on this?

Many thanks!

Comment: Difficult to say anything without seeing the code that doesn't work. Please review the [help] and how to ask questions

Comment: Please take a moment and start a [rubber duck debugging session](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) with your own code. You will notice something very odd in this code. Anyway, to complete your question you should add also the code for AddKYCFolder and a sample of your CSV file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for taking time to look into my question. Apparently, there were some methods that uses parallelism (Parallel.For) that is, I suppose, not compatible with my IIS setup. The log4net error logging greatly helped me to find the source of error.